# how to get this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my table

```
Create table gpscli
(
   cliente int,/*this is my id client*/
   inicio datetime,/*this is start time*/
   fin datetime,/this is finished time**/
   fecha datetime/*this is my date because inicio and fin could be a bad date*/
)
```

Table filled is something as this

```
select cliente, inicio, fin, fecha from gpscli order by fecha, cliente

1 '23-04-2012 10:23:51' '23-04-2012 10:26:38' '23-04-2012 00:00:000'
2 '23-04-2012 10:28:41' '23-04-2012 10:30:12' '23-04-2012 00:00:000'
3 '23-04-2012 10:33:58' '23-04-2012 10:37:24' '23-04-2012 00:00:000'
4 '23-04-2012 10:40:42' '23-04-2012 10:43:12' '23-04-2012 00:00:000'
5 '23-04-2012 10:45:46' '23-04-2012 10:57:18' '23-04-2012 00:00:000'
1 '24-04-2012 10:23:12' '24-04-2012 10:26:28' '24-04-2012 00:00:000'
2 '24-04-2012 10:23:29' '24-04-2012 10:26:58' '24-04-2012 00:00:000'
3 '24-04-2012 10:23:23' '24-04-2012 10:26:56' '24-04-2012 00:00:000'
4 '24-04-2012 10:23:12' '24-04-2012 10:26:28' '24-04-2012 00:00:000'
5 '24-04-2012 10:23:29' '24-04-2012 10:26:58' '24-04-2012 00:00:000'
1 '24-05-2012 10:23:12' '24-05-2012 10:26:28' '24-05-2012 00:00:000'
2 '24-05-2012 10:23:29' '24-05-2012 10:26:58' '24-05-2012 00:00:000'
3 '24-05-2012 10:23:23' '24-05-2012 10:26:56' '24-05-2012 00:00:000'
4 '24-05-2012 10:23:12' '24-05-2012 10:26:28' '24-05-2012 00:00:000'
5 '24-05-2012 10:23:29' '24-05-2012 10:26:58' '24-05-2012 00:00:000'
```

This information is saved by a user at this time would be called "supervisor"

supervisor is person which go store on store question what products client is going to want.

So he (supervisores) moves in car. When he opened a windows (in pockec pc), "inicio" is saved and when supervisor close the windows then "fin" is saved in database.

Now with this information I could get how time supervisor took with a client by mes, but I really need is, how long time supervisor took for move between client by mes.

Not client 1 is necessary the first client for one day, the first client is which has the min on `inicio` column. same for the last client with fin column.

How long time supervisor took for move between client by mes.

I need something as it

- for first client transfer time  is 0.
- for second client, transfer time is `inicio` (this `inicio` column is of current) `- fin` (this `fin` is the former client)
- for third client, transfer time is `inicio` (this inicio column is of current) `- fin` (this `fin` is the former client)

Finally I'll need `group by month,client`

I don't have idea how to get it (without using a loop, I wouldn't like use it)

Comment: You need to try **something** on your own before we help you.

Comment: And naming a column 'date' (`fecha`) is really rather terrible - it's obvious it's a 'date' (except it's a timestamp, so...) - what is it supposed to represent?  You're right though, using loops in SQL is usually frowned upon.  We'd also appreciate some sample output of how you want that sample data to appear, to go along with what you've attempted so far.  Assuming no overlapping timestamps, this isn't too bad, especially as you have access to the necessary features (OLAP functions, although CTEs are nice for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solved

```
create table #datos
(
cliente int,
fecha datetime,
inicio datetime,
fin datetime,
id int identity
)


insert into #datos (cliente,fecha,inicio,fin)
select cliente,fecha,  isnull(t_inicio,'01/01/1900') inicio,isnull(t_fin,'01/01/1900') fin
from gpscli order by  fecha, t_inicio,t_fin


alter table #datos
add idmas1 int

update #datos set idmas1=id+1


select d.cliente, d.fecha, d.inicio, d.fin,d.id,d2.fin fin_anterior from #datos d
inner join #datos d2 on
d.id=d2.idmas1
```

now i have the finished time called as "fin_anterior" and now i can group by client, month or how it was necessary